# Multiple foreign keys pointing to same table - ambiguity issue

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have a MySQL database with an articles table which contains two foreign keys:

- fk_id_user_created
- fk_id_user_edited

The users table looks like this

- pk_id_user
- username

How can these tables be joined, so the usernames of both the users who created and edited the article are returned? There's obviously an ambiguity problem...

EDIT: This does obviously not work:

```
SELECT
    articles.title,
    articles.article,
    users.username as created_by,
    users_username as edited_by
FROM
    articles
LEFT JOIN
    users
ON
    articles.fk_id_user_created = users.pk_id_username
LEFT JOIN
    users
ON
    articles.fk_id_user_edited = users.pk_id_username
```

Comment: "EDIT: This does obviously not work" -- correct, but it will work if you alias the instances of `users`. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Join `users` twice with `articles`, providing an alias to distinguish the instances:

```
select  
  articles.whatever,
  created.username as created_username,
  edited.username as edited_username
from 
  articles
  inner join users as created on articles.fk_id_user_created = created.pk_id_user
  inner join users as edited  on articles.fk_id_user_edited  = edited.pk_id_user
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this, if I understand you correctly?

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO USER (username) VALUES
('A'), ('B');

CREATE TABLE article (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id_created INTEGER,
user_id_edited INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO article (user_id_created, user_id_edited)
VALUES (1, 1), (2,1);

SELECT username 
FROM USER 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id_created FROM article WHERE user_id_created=user_id_edited);

DROP TABLE USER;
DROP TABLE article;
```

And I am not using a join, I am just assuming the user_id_created and user_id_edited will be the same.

Comment: No, an article can be created by one user and edited by another. When an article is created, pk_id_user_edited is NULL. Only when it gets edited, it gets filled with the user id of the user that performed the edit.